# value is not incremented, thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am expecting below to increment c value to be 2. But I am always getting 1 output even after the 2nd thread started.

```
package test.main;

public class TestThread implements Runnable {
    private int c=0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
        c=c+1;
        //wait(1000);
        go();
        }

    }

    private void go() {
        System.out.println("Thread name :"+Thread.currentThread()+" in go() : "+c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("main()");
        Thread t1 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread1");
        Thread t2 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start(); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In thread t1 and t2 you are passing two completely different objects. So in both cases it is incrementing their own c which are not related to each other.

Use a single object

```
    TestThread tt = new TestThread();
    Thread t1 =  new Thread(tt,"thread1");
    Thread t2 =  new Thread(tt,"thread2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created two thread objects.

```
    Thread t1 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread1");
    Thread t2 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread2");
```

And each thread object has its own copy of `c` as its not class level variable. Its instance variable.

So, it will not give you a value 2

Answer (score 1):

Each TestThread object has its own copy of c, so each will be incremented only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread t1 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread1");
Thread t2 =  new Thread(new TestThread(),"thread2");
```

You are creating two different instances of TestThread and

```
private int c=0;
```

is an instance variable(not a class variable). So it is expected for c to be 1 after run() is executed for each Thread.

Comment: Thanks everyone,everyone replied correctly, but accepting this as it is the first answer. I don't have sufficient points to do +1 for others.